# How to switch windows to specific visible buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, selected-window

Is there a command that allows me to have my cursor switch windows to a specified buffer? Something that looks like

```
(switch-to-specific-window-command "buffer-name")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `switch-to-buffer`, bound to `C-x b`, does what you're looking for.  Likewise, `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, bound to `C-x 4 b`, and `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`, bound to `C-x 5 b`.

Command `pop-to-buffer` also does what you request, slightly differently.

---

From your comments, it's not clear what you want.  The goalposts seem to be moving...

Now you seem to say you want to do *nothing* if the buffer is already in the `selected-window`?  In that case, `pop-to-buffer` does just what you want, I think.  Have you tried it?

Or if you don't want to use `pop-to-buffer`, but that is anyway what you want (do nothing if already visiting the buffer in the selected window), then this does that also:

```lisp
(defun foo (buffer)
  (interactive "b")
  (unless (equal (get-buffer buffer) (window-buffer (selected-window)))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer)))
```

Comment: This would switch to the buffer in the current window. But what I would like to do is to go to the window that already is visiting buffer that I am specifying

Comment: No. `pop-to-buffer` uses another window, as does `switch-to-buffer-other-window` (`C-x 4 b`).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant that `switch-to-buffer` would behave in the manner I stated in my comment. `switch-to-buffer-other-window` would not do the job, as if lets say i was already in the window of the buffer that i wanted to switch to. it would switch to another window and open that buffer there. What I want is for a function that would go to that already open window, regardless of whichever window is in focus

Comment: If you haven't tried `pop-to-buffer`, please try it. If you *have* tried it, in what way does it fall short?